# Почему происходит com.github.vbauer.yta.service.basic.exception.YTranslateException при работе с Яндекс.Переводчик API?

Tags: java, android, яндекс-переводчик

Получил API ключ Яндекса, чтобы использовать в Android приложении, вроде бы должен работать, получал через сервисный аккаунт Яндекса.
Для перевода текста использую данный метод:

```
    private String translate(String text) {
    YTranslateApi api = new YTranslateApiImpl(API_TRANSLATE_KEY);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        Translation translate = api.translationApi().translate(text, Language.EN);
        return translate.text();
    }

        return "";
    }
```

`api translate key` - это тот api, что я получил. При вызове метода вылетает данное исключение на строке:

```
Translation translate = api.translationApi().translate(text, Language.EN);
```

Исключение:

```
com.github.vbauer.yta.service.basic.exception.YTranslateException: Could not call method &quot;/translate&quot; using {format=plain, text=аааапп, lang=en}
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.transport.impl.RestClientImpl.callMethod(RestClientImpl.java:85)
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.basic.AbstractApi.callMethod(AbstractApi.java:49)
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.fraction.impl.TranslationApiImpl.translate(TranslationApiImpl.java:81)
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.fraction.impl.TranslationApiImpl.translate(TranslationApiImpl.java:63)
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.fraction.impl.TranslationApiImpl.translate(TranslationApiImpl.java:51)
    at com.example.soundtranslator.FragmentHome$1.onClick(FragmentHome.java:67)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1565)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
    at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:41)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:178)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:144)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:86)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:176)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.transport.impl.RestClientImpl.callMethod(RestClientImpl.java:64)
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.basic.AbstractApi.callMethod(AbstractApi.java:49)&#160;
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.fraction.impl.TranslationApiImpl.translate(TranslationApiImpl.java:81)&#160;
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.fraction.impl.TranslationApiImpl.translate(TranslationApiImpl.java:63)&#160;
    at 
com.github.vbauer.yta.service.fraction.impl.TranslationApiImpl.translate(TranslationApiImpl.java:51)&#160;
    at com.example.soundtranslator.FragmentHome$1.onClick(FragmentHome.java:67)&#160;
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)&#160;
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)&#160;
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)&#160;
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)&#160;
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)&#160;
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)&#160;
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)&#160;
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так, метод делал с помощью этого [материала](https://github.com/vbauer/yandex-translate-api).

Новая ошибка:

```
   com.github.vbauer.yta.service.basic.exception.YTranslateException: Could not call method &quot;/translate&quot; using {format=plain, text=Привет, lang=en}
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.transport.impl.RestClientImpl.callMethod(RestClientImpl.java:85)
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.basic.AbstractApi.callMethod(AbstractApi.java:49)
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.fraction.impl.TranslationApiImpl.translate(TranslationApiImpl.java:81)
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.fraction.impl.TranslationApiImpl.translate(TranslationApiImpl.java:63)
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.fraction.impl.TranslationApiImpl.translate(TranslationApiImpl.java:51)
    at com.example.soundtranslator.FragmentHome$1$1.run(FragmentHome.java:70)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
 Caused by: com.github.vbauer.yta.service.basic.exception.YTranslateApiException: Can not retrieve information from Yandex Translate service. Status: 403
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.basic.ApiStatus.check(ApiStatus.java:69)
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.transport.impl.RestClientImpl.callMethod(RestClientImpl.java:71)
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.basic.AbstractApi.callMethod(AbstractApi.java:49)&#160;
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.fraction.impl.TranslationApiImpl.translate(TranslationApiImpl.java:81)&#160;
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.fraction.impl.TranslationApiImpl.translate(TranslationApiImpl.java:63)&#160;
    at com.github.vbauer.yta.service.fraction.impl.TranslationApiImpl.translate(TranslationApiImpl.java:51)&#160;
    at com.example.soundtranslator.FragmentHome$1$1.run(FragmentHome.java:70)&#160;
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)&#160;
```

Comment: вы на главном потоке вызываете API, вам нужно создать отдельный поток и выполнять запрос там

Comment: @Komdosh не помогло или помогло на половину, ошибка всё на той же строке вылетает

Comment: 403 это forbidden ошибка, запрос ушёл, но сервер не может ответить, т.к. у вас недостаточно прав. мб неправильный ключ сгенерировали?

Comment: @Komdosh вполне возможно, я просто создал какой то api ключ через сервисный аккаунт, не выбирая для чего он мне нужен. Я смотрел инструкцию от Яндекса как получается api через консоль, но там куча разных ошибок вылезает, вы не знаете как получить api ключ для переводчика?